# Change Docker base image of running containers

Tags: docker, openshift

I have been using alpine as the base image for the docker containers which are getting deployed in openshift platform. The reason being it was light weight and faster to download. Now due to security and support reasons we need to change it to Redhat image. Although it's big in size but our application needs and better security with support is priority. Hence I want to change the base image of alpine to redhat. What is the best approach to achieve this without impacting the production workload?

Should I change the Dockerfile with new base image, deploy, test and verify the application and decommission the old containers? or is their a faster way? Since there are more than 150 microservices running on these containers.

Comment: I doubt there is a faster way.. Since containers are immutable by nature so the old ones cannot be updated in place and the new ones created with the process you described (change the Dockerfile with new base image, deploy, test and verify the application) will need to replace the old ones.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot change the base image, so I think the best approach is to change it from `Dockerfile` and build a new image to test. But in the meantime you can enable Maintenance Mode or like this in your services to tell users hey we're going to be off temporarily soon and we'll back later:)

Comment: @Saeed You can build new images, test them, iterate, and finally push them to a registry while the old system is still running.  Hopefully in the end switching involves just changing the `image:` in a `docker-compose.yml` file or a Kubernetes manifest, which can be done fairly quickly.